# Как поставить свою фотографию если сервер вернул 404

Tags: javascript, css, изображения

Здравствуйте, пишу на Vanilla Js. Код возвращает ссылку на изображение с сервера, а потом я ставлю ее как background-image url. Но как сделать так, если сервер вернул 404 вместо пустой картинки поставить свою с ошибкой?

Comment: Непонял вопроса

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror почитайте эту статью, возможно она поможет :)

Comment: Статья выше не поможет. А вот хак из [этого ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5058336/4981937) может помочь. Только его для ваниллы переписать надо. Если вкратце, то создаете картинку в памяти, проверяете, загрузилась ли она, и только после этого помещаете в `background-image`. Если не загрузилась, то помещаете другую картинку с ошибкой. Но вообще ваш подход в корне неверен. Контент нельзя в `background-image` пихать. А если вы туда не контент, а оформление пихаете, то вопрос лишь в том, почему вы не можете гарантировать наличие картинки, которая является частью дизайна.

Answer (score 0):

Если `ssilka_servera.jpg` не является прозрачным, можно использовать несколько фонов:

```
background-image: url('ssilka_servera.jpg'), url('default.jpg');
```

`default.jpg` будет виден только если `ssilka_servera.jpg` не доступен